# How to mute iPhone running iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios5, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi, mute

I know this question is already asked quite some time. And I read all the topics at stackoverflow.
But there isn't a satisfying answer to my problem.

I'd like to mute my iPhone running iOS 5 programmatically. Many would say it isn't possible with public frameworks. I'm aware of that. The App I'm planning to code is for personal use only. I do not intend to sell it over the AppStore (yet?).

My research brought me to the conclusion, that there my be several ways to achieve muting an iPhone programmatically.

1. Use private frameworks
2. Hook functions or methods which are playing sounds
3. Replace default sounds (like ringtone, MailSent, iMessage, usw...)

Some thoughts to the above mentioned methods:

1. I class-dumped all headers of the private frameworks (in my Xcode-Installation) and didn't find functions which indicate (by their function name) to the wanted behavior
2. I think it's possible, but I do not know the functions to be hooked. Therefore, it would be quite some effort for to make this work (and I think I do not want to do this)
3. Giving it a second thought, this might not be a good solution. Maybe you can change the sounds. But then the phone isn't mute at all (games, YouTube,...)

I had given `AVSystemController` a chance using the methods `changeActiveCategoryVolumeBy` and `setVolumeTo` but those won't mute my phone but set the minimal volume of the ringer to 0.06 (or something).

There has to be a way to completely mute the iPhone, RingToggle (jailbroken app) is doing it quite good.

Does anyone has a idea how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'll be able to mute the phone from a sandboxed app, even using private frameworks.

What RingToggle probably does is hook into the springboard and use springboard's methods to mute the phone; they are probably using a MobileSubstrate extension.

Comment: I'm afraid you might be right.  But I would use MobileSubstrate extensions only if I'd knew the right things to do...